# Creating a child component within a parent component in Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-spark, vue-component

I am trying to figure out how to make one component inside of another one in VueJS.  For instance, something like this, which unfortunately does not work (the child component appears to do nothing):

http://www.webpackbin.com/NyI0PzaL-

I am equally interested in doing this using inline-templates as much as by using the .vue file extension method as shown above.

Here is the code from the non-working example above:

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Child from './Child.vue'

new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  components: { App, Child }
})
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <app></app>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
      <h1>{{ parent_msg }}</h1>
      <child></child>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      parent_msg: 'Hello From the Parent!'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Child.vue**

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ child_msg }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      child_msg: 'Hello From the Child!'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Even though this above example is hosted on webpackbin.com, in the two projects where I would like to use this, I am using Laravel in one along with Laravel Spark in the other.  In the plain Laravel app, I'm primarily using .vue files, and in the Laravel Spark app, I'm primarily using inline-templates.  I'd be especially grateful for any working samples.  Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Linus for his answer below.  It appears I need these changes to register the child component globally in my **main.js** file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Child from './Child.vue'
Vue.component('child', Child);

new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  components: { App, Child }
})
```

Alternatively, in order to keep the child component local to be used within the parent, I could change the parent component (**App.vue**) as follows:

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ parent_msg }}</h1>
  <div>
      <child></child>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Child from './Child.vue';
export default {
  components: {Child},
  data () {
    return {
      parent_msg: 'Hello from the parent component!'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your code is right.  Are you running it through the vueify extension? Your webpackbin is not the same code here.

Comment: Move your child import to the app.vue and add the component hash there for the child.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You registered the `Child` component locally in the main instance, so it is not available in App.vue

Remove it form the main instance and add it to App.vue:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
      <h1>{{ parent_msg }}</h1>
      <child></child>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Child from './child.vue'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      parent_msg: 'Hello From the Parent!'
    }
  },
  components: {child: Child}
}
</script>
```

..or register it globally with `Vue.component('child', Child)` in your main.js file. Then it's available everywhere.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I will test it out when I get a chance.

Comment: Your answer appears to be working, at least on WebpackBin.  Hopefully I can get it to work in Laravel now, as well!

Comment: Great solution, could you tell me how to display 'parent_msg' to child component and vice versa ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4527328/raju-shrestha  - Check this out for communicating between nested components https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/difference-between-props-and-data